# NPM RUN WATCH doesn't finish it's job

Tags: laravel, npm

Hi everyone I'm new in laravel, I'm using laravel 9, i tried to run (npm run watch) and it's about 30 mins nothing happened,

[image]
this's the message i get.

Hopefully I get some answers,
thank you in advance

Comment: `watch` keeps running to intercept changes you make to your sources and compile them again. Is that not working?

Comment: Did you try running `npm run development` first ? what results did you get ? and dont post images of console, copy the text and add it to your question alongside the image if you want.

Comment: `npm run watch` doesn't seem to be in the laravel 9 boilerplate package.json anymore. What does your `package.json` look like?

Answer (score 0):

i have tried npm run dev it doesn't work , so i replace it with npm run build .
this is what my package.json look like:

```
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "watch": "npm-watch",
    "build": "vite build"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "postcss": "^8.4.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
    "vite": "^4.0.3"
},
"dependencies": {
    "npm-watch": "^0.11.0"
},
"watch": {
    "build": {
        "patterns": [
            "src"
        ],
        "extensions": "js,jsx"
    }
}
```

}

I added ( "watch": "npm-watch",)